# Pig null data frame is generating data when used inside 'foreach' clause

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig, apache-pig-grunt

Pardon me if I am using wrong standard pig names as I am new to it.

I have 2 dataframes in Pig (X and Y). Both having variables: j1 and j2.
I am doing below operations:

```
A = JOIN X by (j1) left outer, Y by (j1);

SPLIT A into B (IF Y::j1 IS NULL), C otherwise;

D = FOREACH B GENERATE X::j2;
```

Here, if we do DUMP B then there is no data inside it. 
If we do DUMP C then data d1 appears.
But when I do DUMP D then the same data d1 appears, which is wired because B did not have any data points.

Can someone tell why it is happening?

NOTE: I have tried:

1. Storing B and then looking manually into part files but nothing is there in B.
2. I have also Stored A, then came out of session and then started the session in grunt and Loaded A and then executed last 2 lines of the code (i.e split and foreach). And when I am doing this then the code is working as expected and DUMP D is not showing any output data (which is correct).

**FOUND THE SOLUTION:**
 It was not actually the Pig issue. It was Jar issue which I was using to read data and hence creating data frames X and Y. Basically Jar was not able to read the csv file properly which is creating issue in join operation above.

Comment: Are you sure that your second statement runs without error? You need to tell Pig which `j1` you are referring to: `X::j1` or `Y::j1`. The decision might result in `B` having or not having data due to the left outer join. While adding `DUMP` statements are you sure that none of your other statements are changing?

Comment: Hi, apologies for the typo. I have added Y::j1 in the code. And now the code is exactly same with no changes at all. So no other statements are changing while dumping.

Comment: Can you share a sample input, expected output and actual output?  It's not clear to me what "d1" is referring to (since your script does not have any "d1".)

Comment: Hi, the issue is resolved. It was not actually the Pig issue. It was Jar issue which I was using to read data and hence creating data frames  X and Y.